# Javascript variable initialization syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, variable-assignment

I'm working with a javascript (Ext JS 4) project, and I came across this:

```
{
    init: function() {
        var me = this, desktopCfg;
        ...
    }
}
```

What exactly is being assigned to 'me' in this situation?

Comment: I think I figured this out: It's basically initializing two variables but only supplying a value to the first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
var me = this, desktopCfg;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var me = this;
var desktopCfg;
```

as `=` has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `,`.

See also: [the manual for `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) which has examples of this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

the object this.  the parser goes down the instructions and sees a comma separated list of the two instructions 
    var me = this;
    desktopCfg;
so the variable me gets the whole object that it is in.